# Subscribing to Multiple iOS Subscriptions

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I have a question about setting up auto-renewing subscriptions on iOS.

In my app, a user is able to be subscribed to multiple subscriptions at the same time. Is there a way to find out which subscriptions a user is currently subscribed to. In android is is as simple as loading the owned purchases from google via the billing processor. Is there an equivalent in iOS or do I need to do something else. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found the best way to do all InAppPurchasing was to use the library: SwiftyStoreKit. It makes everything a lot simpler and streamlines the whole process. It is well supported and well documented.

Here is the link to the github repository: https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit

Answer (score 0):

You cannot determine on your own whether a user is subscribed or not. The only possibility for you to determine if a user is subscribed is to either validate preexisting receipts or restore purchases. I recommend you to watch the WWDC sessions regarding StoreKit at [developers.apple.com](https://developers.apple.com), use [Swifty StoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) as it saves you some of the hazzle and read Apple's documentation.